# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /path/to/cacert.pem

Tags: python, pip, certificate, oserror

ive been having this issue for close to 10 months now and still cant seem to fix it, is there anyway someone is able to help, ive reinstalled python and pip and still cant fix it after spending hours researching this error, im not too sure if im doing something incorrectly or if i need to reinstall windows, in the end of the day im not too sure but is someone able to help me out